# Inserir dados em entidade relacionada @OneToOne no Spring Boot(Jpa, hibernate, Postgre)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

### Tenho um relacionamento unidimensional(1:1) em que o contrato possue um inquilino.

**Class User**

```
@Table(name="TB_USER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "cpf")
    private String cpf;
    @NotBlank
    private String nome;
    @NotBlank
    private String email;
}
```

**Class Inquilino**

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="cpf")
public class Inquilino extends User{


    private Boolean status = true;
    @NotBlank
    private String nomeFiador;

    @NotBlank
    private String telefone;
}
```

**Class Contrato**

```
@Table(name = "TB_CONTRATO")
public class Contrato {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name= "id")
private Long id;

private Boolean status = true;

@NotBlank
private String numContrato;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "cpf")
private Inquilino inquilino;
```

**Fiz um CRUD simples, e minha intenção seria ir criando os inquilinos e quando fosse criar o contrato,  mandar no body da requisição no json. Porem o erro no spring boot aparece:**

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tb_user_pkey"
> Detalhe: Key (cpf)=(123213) already exists.

**Deduzi que eu não poderia criar o contrato com algo que ja foi criado por conta da identificação(mais dedução mesmo. Porem para o projeto, eu gostaria de ter uma lista de inquilinos para serem escolhidos e depois associados.**

Espero não ter complicado o entendimento.

Answer (score 0):

O cascade é uma operação de persistência no banco, ele irá salvar todas as entidades relacionadas à sua entidade pai.

https://www.devmedia.com.br/cascade-hibernate-conhecendo-diferentes-tipos/28892

Como você está usando o cascade no seu relacionamento de inquilino, ele irá persistir e salvar Inquilino junto com Contrato. Por isso o erro da chave duplicada de cpf, está tentando salvar essa entidade que já foi salva anteriormente.

Para corrigir o seu problema remova a operação cascade deixando apenas o mapeamento @OneToOne de seu relacionamento, e tente inserir na sua camada de serviço manualmente um inquilino já salvo em sua aplicação.